# Mongo text search throws error in a collection but not on another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this text search when I run it in worfklows collection in doesn't break:

```
db.getCollection('workflows').aggregate([{
    $match: {
      ownerId: ObjectId('5ea898bbc7e7e248e1f68a29'),
      $text: {
        $search: '"122746-is-01"',
        $caseSensitive: false
      }
    }
}])
```

this collection has a text index looking like this:
[image]

### Error

now I try to do the exact same query as above but changing collection to `documents`

```
db.getCollection('documents').aggregate([{   
    $match: {
      ownerId: ObjectId('5ea898bbc7e7e248e1f68a29'),
      $text: {
        $search: '"122746-is-01"',
        $caseSensitive: false
      }
    }   
}])
```

And get error:

```
Failed to execute script.

Error:
Socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] server [network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host 'localhost:27017' ]
```

The documents collection has a text index created in the exact same way as the above index (workflows collection text index).

I'm using mongo v4.4.6, but not sure that is relevant.

Comment: you are using replica? If you are using replica can you ensure you enter all the host/ip

Comment: I'm currently trying this at localhost yes we do use a replica set host and ip is correct for localhost @SomeoneSpecial

Comment: The error says otherwise. It is not related to the query. Connection errors happen way before you can send any query to the database. Show how you set up the replica, and how you connect to it

Comment: the replica connection string should be in the form of mongodb://user:pass@host1:port,host2:port,host3:port, it cannot be standalone localhost:27017 as localhost:27017 may not be primary. If possible, for development, use a standalone.